# WireShark and Facebook

Tags: privacy, wireshark, facebook

Some time ago i try Wireshark at my home local network just for see how it works. I scan the connection of my mac to the router and also to other external ips. The flow of connections were high when i was surfing on web and low when the browser was shut down. My question is: why also when all browser were turned off i was able to see some Facebook connection between my mac and their servers?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the Wireshark trace for those remaining connections ?

Comment: Or post the capture file?

Comment: What state are these TCP/IP connection in? If they're CLOSE_WAIT or TIME_WAIT then see here: http://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that the connections haven't closed yet they are waiting for any delayed packets before they close completely(if they're CLOSE_WAIT(Facebook closed the connection) or TIME_WAIT(You closed the connection), these connections will typically close on their own within 5 mins.

Another possibility is that your browser keeps some tabs JavaScript running after closing because of a feature or a bug. A good test for that is to look in your task manager for anything related to your browser.